# passing a variable from Javascript to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown list where users can select multiple options. I stored the selected options in a String variable in this format : [value of first selected option],[value of second selected option]...

Now i want to pass the value of this variable from my Javascript in file 1  to PHP variable in file 2 using Ajax. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://querybuilder.js.org/dist/selectize/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container"> 
    <form method="post" action="displayData.php" id="multiple_select_form">
     <select name="columns" id="columns" class="form-control selectpicker"  multiple>
      <option value="Country">Country</option>
      <option value="Customer Name">Customer Name</option>
      <option value="Order Date">Order Date</option>
      <option value="Address">Address</option>
     </select>
    </form>
   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-info center-block" id="btn-get">Submit</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
  $('#btn-get').on('click', function() {
        var selectedOptions = [];
        $.each($(".selectpicker option:selected"), function(){            
            selectedOptions.push("[" + $(this).val() + "]");
        });
        var myVar = selectedOptions.join(",");
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'displayData.php',
                    data: { testVariable : myVar },
                    success: function(data)
                    {alert(data);}
                           });
  $("#multiple_select_form").submit();
});
</script>
```

I added alert(data) on success in my Ajax to see if the variable got the correct value. It's working but when form is submited and the displayData.php is loaded I get error Undefined index: testVariable

displayData.php is a simple test file

```
<?php   
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$variable = $_POST['testVariable'];
print_r($variable);
?>
```

Can anyone explain me what can be the issue ? I believe that the Ajax is written correctly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The issue is because when you submit the `form` (ie. not through AJAX) the  data is sent in the argument based on the control `name`, ie. `columns`. If you're not intending to submit the form normally, and only want the AJAX behaviour you should move the submit button inside the form and hook the event handler to the `submit` event of that `form` element.

Comment: There's no field named `$testVariable` in your form, only in your ajax.

Comment: why you need to submit the data two times to server  (one from the ajax and other from form submit ) i think you can remove $("#multiple_select_form").submit();

Comment: @BikeshMAnnur  
I removed $("#multiple_select_form").submit(); from my javascript and the form tag in my html and kept just the select. when i click submit it doesn't redirect me to the new page. I added also location.href = "http://*****/displayData.php"; and still nothing. Any ideas please ?

Comment: If the requirement is to only display data then why you need to use ajax ? you can simply use the form submit, if you want to change the form data then you can use jquery submit function to alter the data (https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: @BikeshMAnnur  I just want to use the value of my variable in Javascript tag in another php page. After all the forums i checked i thought Ajax is the best solution. First time i am trying it so i am confused and i didn't know i am submitting the data twice

Comment: If you are using ajax, the data will be submitted to server like as background process. page will not reload or refresh only this scenario ajax will be better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://querybuilder.js.org/dist/selectize/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container"> 
    <form method="post" action="displayData.php" id="multiple_select_form">
     <select name="columns" id="columns" class="form-control selectpicker"  multiple>
      <option value="Country">Country</option>
      <option value="Customer Name">Customer Name</option>
      <option value="Order Date">Order Date</option>
      <option value="Address">Address</option>
     </select>


    <input type="hidden" name="testVariable" id="testVariable">


    </form>
   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-info center-block" id="btn-get">Submit</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
  $('#btn-get').on('click', function() {
        var selectedOptions = [];
        $.each($(".selectpicker option:selected"), function(){            
            selectedOptions.push("[" + $(this).val() + "]");
        });
        $("#testVariable").val(selectedOptions.join(","));


  $("#multiple_select_form").submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You're making *two* requests to `displayData.php`.  One is an AJAX request, with the value set in a field called `testVariable`, and one is a normal form submit with the value set in a field called `columns`.  The error is happening on the second request.

If your intent is to use AJAX, then remove the following code:

```
$("#multiple_select_form").submit();
```

You might even remove the `<form>` wrapper entirely, since you're identifying the elements directly and not really using the form itself for serialization or anything.  (If you ever put a button *inside* the form it will automatically submit unless you explicitly handle the event to cancel that behavior.)

Conversely, if you *do* want to submit the form, then you can remove the JavaScript code entirely and move the submit button to be inside the `<form>` wrapper.  And, of course, rename the form element to what your server-side code expects:

```
<select name="testVariable" ...
```

Comment: I removed $("#multiple_select_form").submit(); from my javascript and the form tag in my html and kept just the select. when i click submit it doesn't redirect me to the new page. I added also location.href = "http://*****/displayData.php"; and still nothing. Any ideas please ?

Comment: @JuniorDev: Well, there's no code there that *would* perform a redirect.  And, so that point, if you want to navigate to a different page then why use AJAX at all?  It sounds like what you *want* is the second option in this answer, to put the submit button inside the form and remove all of the JavaScript code entirely.  (And, of course, rename the form element.)